# Why is my mongoose query taking so long time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been using node-application with mongodb atlas, to create a dynamic multi-tenant application(via useDb of mongoose) where the no. of tenants is dynamic. mongoose queries are taking way too long to be considered normal(~6s for fetching documents via mongoose.Model.find() irrespective of no. of documents).

```
console.time()
var {
    tennantDb,
    Item
} = await connectToTennant(/*req.body.restaurantId*/)
console.log("below is timelog for useDb to a tennant")
console.timeLog()
const items = await Item.find({isDeleted:{$ne:true}}).lean()
console.log("below is timelog item search")
console.timeEnd()
console.log(`no. of items fetched ${items.length}`);
```

the console reads as :

```
MongoDB Connected!
below is timelog for useDb to a tennant
default: 38.459ms
below is timelog item search
default: 6.649s
no. of items fetched 58
MongoDB Connected!
GET /restrox/api/restaurant/61a9be76ac8f663ebc6ee36d/dish/ 200 29796.883 ms - 28782
```

our db config can be seen in the code below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connectDB = async ()=>{
    const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        autoIndex: true,
        connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
        socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    })
    connection.on('open', () =>{
        console.log("MongoDB Connected!")
    })
    connection.on('error', (err) =>{
        console.error("Connection failed:", err);
        process.exit(0);
    })
    return connection
}
module.exports = {connectDB}
```

in server.js

```
//connection to database
global.clientConnection = connectDB()
```

in connectToTennant

```
// me and myschema is replaced by other existent scehamas to be used
//importing schema for tenant database
const mySchema = require('../schema/me.schema')

const databasePrefix = "restrox_database_"

exports.connectToTennant = async (tennantId)=>{
    try {
        const dbConnection = await global.clientConnection;
        const tennantDb = await dbConnection.useDb(`${databasePrefix}${tennantId}`,{ 
            useCache: true,
            noListener: true
        });
        // make schema to a tennant model
        const myModel = tennantDb.model('me', mySchema);

        const [Me] = await Promise.all([myModel])
        
        return { tennantDb, Me}
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to connect to ${tennantId} database!!`, error);
    }
}
```

Comment: anything that takes longer than 100ms should be logged by the mongod, see what that log tells you about the query.

Comment: @Joe thank you for the concern, seems like it was a problem with mongoDB pool size which defaulted to 0, tried the same query in mongoDBCompass, executed pretty much instantaneously experimented with the options of createConnection and minPoolSize being set to some integer(50 in this case) worked. Although this still doesn't answer the ~6s required to open a single connection and execute the query, the culprit was found to be minPoolSize.